# Is the Legendre transformation continuous?

Tags: real-analysis, convex-analysis, convex-geometry

Is the Legendre transformation continuous on the space of the convex $\mathbb R^{n} \to \mathbb R$ functions for the topology of the simple convergence?

First the limit of a sequence of convex function is a convex function in regard of the simple convergence. And it's easy to see that

$$u^{*}(x) \le \liminf_{n} u_{n}^{*}$$

So can we conclude?

Comment: What is "simple convergence"? This does not exist as a common term.

Comment: What you ask does not make sense anyways for if $Conv(\mathbb R^n)$ denotes the set of convex functions on $\mathbb R^n$, then the Legendre transformation $L$ does not map $Conv(\mathbb R^n)$ to itself because the domain of $L(f)$ may not be $\mathbb R^n$. Would you like to extend $Lf$ somehow to a convex function on $\mathbb R^n$ if $dom(f)\neq\mathbb R^n$?

Comment: I meant pointwise convergence, my apologies.

Comment: The main issue is my second comment. If you don't clarify this, you won't get any answers.

Comment: Yes, you're right. Thank you I have to think about it.

Comment: You could fix a convex set $V\subset\mathbb R^n$, set $D(V) := \{f\in Conv(\mathbb R^n) : V=dom L(f)\}$, and ask whether $L : D(V)\to Conv(V)$ is continuous.

Comment: Hi, I hope you are still with me. I think I can change my question to avoid it. Let $X$ a finit subset of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$.

And $f : w \in \mathbb{R}^{X} \rightarrow f(w) \in \mathbb{R}^{X}$ such as $f(w)(x_{i}) = w^{*}(x_{i})$.

Is $f$ continuous ? (We consider $\mathbb{R}^{X}$ as a normed vector space).

I wish you a good day, thank you.